Power BI - Show Counts for last 7 days including zeros
I am trying to count occurrences of a QR code entry in to a DB each day and display the last 7 days of counts. I would like to include zero counts.
The top graph is using QR Code (count) for the Y axis and the filter is correctly applied. The problem is it skips days where there are no occurrences.
The bottom graph uses the following measure for the Y axis.
Count = COUNT('db'[QR_Code]) + 0
It now counts the zeros but doesn't apply the Date filter correctly.
I can't seem to get this to work, please help!
enter image description here

Is the Interaction from your Slicer to Bottom Chart set to no impact or filter?

The bottom chart has the date as a filter, both charts do. On the bottom chart, the filter seems to be filtering out all counts to zero (except the last 7 days) but not limiting the number of points displayed.

Is Date_Modified  a column on your QR Code Table or is it from a Date Table?

If you don't have a separate Date dimension table, it won't show up. You need to put the date from the Date dimension on the x-axis.

@NickA Date modified is a column in the same table (it gives the date/time that the scan came in).

@Pieter The X axis uses the Date Modified column which is linked to the QR code data. There isn't a separate data dimension table, Would I have to create a dynamic table which has the dates for the last 7 days?

You would need to create a date table, create a relationship between the Date column of the Date Table and the Entry_Date of the QR Code Table. Then you can  use DateTable[Date] as the slicer and x-axis of the chart to get your desired outcome.
Simple Date Table Code:
DateTable = 
CALENDAR(MIN('QR_Code_Log'[Entry_Date]), MAX('QR_Code_Log'[Entry_Date]))

